# extract json to excel table using vba

Tags: json, excel, vba, converters

I try to extract json data to excel table using vba. I have installed VBA-JSON and turned on Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

the json request delivers:

{
  "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
  "RESULT": {
    "aid": "17903",
    "ean": 4003483179030,
    "title": " Manzanita, sandgestrahlt, verzweigt, 90-100 cm",
    "shortdesc": " Echte Äste direkt aus der Natur, ca. 90-100 Zentimeter lang. Wunderschön für natürliche Dekorationen oder als Kontrast zu Pflanzgefäßen und Vasen aus anderen Materialien. Sauber, da sandgestrahlt. Jedes Stück ein Unikat (Abbildungen beispielhaft).",
    "longdesc": "Ein besonderer Blickfang sind Dekorationen aus echten, natürlichen Materialien wie MANZANITA Zweigen. Die echten Zweige eignen sich perfekt als Kontrast zu Pflanzgefäßen und Vasen aus anderen Materialien. Sauber, da sandgestrahlt. Jedes Stück ein Unikat (Abbildungen beispielhaft).",
    "length": "0",
    "width": "0",
    "height": "90",
    "weight": "1",
    "pic01": "17903_manzanitasandblastedbranchy.jpg",
    "pic02": "17903_manzanitasandblastedbranchy~01.jpg",
    "pic03": "17903_manzanitasandblastedbranchy~02.jpg",
    "pic04": "",
    "pic05": "",
    "pic06": "",
    "pic07": "",
    "pic08": "",
    "pic09": "",
    "pic10": "",
    "pic11": "",
    "pic12": "",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "id": "oxattribute1013",
        "title": "Aktueller Katalog",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": "oxattribute1021",
        "title": "Aktueller Katalog - Seitenzahl",
        "value": "238-1"
      },
      {
        "id": "oxattribute1007",
        "title": "Paket - Versand",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": "oxattribute1020",
        "title": "Serie",
        "value": "MANZANITA"
      },
      {
        "id": "oxattribute1019",
        "title": "Funktionsname",
        "value": "Ast"
      },
      {
        "id": "oxattribute1018",
        "title": "Farbbezeichnung",
        "value": "sandgestrahlt"
      },
      {
        "id": "oxattribute1005",
        "title": "Speditionsversand",
        "value": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}

i wrote it in a excel cell (1,1) and parsed it using jsonconverter.

with the code

```
Sub Jsonauslesenbenny()

Dim jsonText As String
Dim jsonObject As Object

Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Tabelle1")

jsonText = ws.Cells(1, 1)

Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)

i = 3



For Each item In jsonObject("RESULT")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = item("aid")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = item("ean")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = item("title")

i = i + 1
Next



End Sub
```

in that way the items "aid" to "pic12" can be written in excel cell.

I dont get it work to write the items after "attributes" in excel table cells.

how can I write "id", "title" and "value" from the json data to the excel table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Jsonauslesenbenny()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, jsonObject As Object, jsonText As String, i As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Tabelle1")
    jsonText = ws.Cells(1, 1)
    Set jsonObject = JSONConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)
    i = 3

    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells(i, 1).Value = jsonObject("RESULT")("aid")
        .Cells(i, 2).Value = jsonObject("RESULT")("ean")
        .Cells(i, 3).Value = jsonObject("RESULT")("title")
    End With
End Sub
```

To get the attibutes

```
Sub GetAttributes()
    Dim itm, ws As Worksheet, jsonObject As Object, jsonText As String, i As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Tabelle1")
    jsonText = ws.Cells(1, 1)
    Set jsonObject = JSONConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)
    i = 3

    For Each itm In jsonObject("RESULT")("attributes")
        With Sheets(1)
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = itm("id")
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = itm("title")
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = itm("value")
        End With
        i = i + 1
    Next itm
End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn´t work and i get an error in

Comment: Be specific and tell what's the error and in what line does it happen exactly?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn´t work and i get an error in both procedures. in Jsonauslesenbenny () I got the error in the row  .Cells(i, 1).Value = jsonObject("RESULT")("aid") In the procedure Sub GetAttributes() I got an error in row For Each itm In jsonObject("RESULT")("attributes"). The error is in both cases "Ungültiger Prozeduraufruf oder ungültiges Argument (Fehler 5)"

Comment: Sorry, it works fine with your code. when i tested it I have taken an other json request result.